# checking user role and restriction for user

Tags: php, mysql, database

Let suppose i’m working an application `( PHP & MYSQL )`
and in this app has an `user table` for storing user information.
Users `table column name`

`id user_name   password    role`

There are some user role for accessing application.
`i) All`
`ii)    Read only`
`iii)   Edit`
`iv)    Entery only`
`v)     Etc.`

I’was store there role separated with `,` now i’m not understanding how to check user role and code for that application...

I’m trying something like that..

```
$roles = implode(“.”,$_SESSION[‘user_role’]);  
If( array_key_exist(“all”,$roles) && array_key_exist(“edit”,$roles) ){
    // do some stuff...
}
If( array_key_exist(“read only”,$roles) ){
    // do some stuff...
}
```

Is it right way to do/checking role or please give me some suggestion if there is another best way to do so.. thanks

Comment: Well, one way to go about that is query the user from the database and then evaluate their `role` field.  You could use a `switch` to execute code based on their `role`.  However you may wish to adjust your permissions model a little.  A permission like `Entry only` might fit better with `Edit`.  Another thing you could do is simply evaluate the operation and make sure the logged in user is allowed to do that operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assuming your `$_SESSION` contains the string with comma separated roles, you need to `explode(',', $_SESSION['user_role'])` it to get an array of roles.

To check if a role is contained in that array, use `in_array("All", $roles)` instead of `array_key_exists()` which will only search for keys, not values.

Comment: Yes there were couple of mistake because i wrote all code directly here without practice any ways thanks for correction..

Comment: You should try running your code first before asking. There are plenty of tutorials on the web.

Comment: thanks andy.. please share me some link of tutorial the topic of relevant question.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/ is just one example to get you started. However, I did not thoroughly check the contents.